# For which primes $p$ is $p^2+p+1$ prime as well?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am looking to find out for which prime numbers $p$, the number $p^2+p+1$ is also prime. The first few are $$2,3,5,17,41,59,71,89,101$$ I tried to take the relation modulo $p+1$ and it turns out that in $\mathbb{Z}_{p+1}$, $p^2+p+1$ is $\hat{1}$, but I can't continue from here.

Comment: ok would you mind clarifying what you mean by $\hat{1}$ for me please

Comment: When divided by p+1 gives residue 1

Comment: the integer remainder of the division of $p_n(p_n+1)+1$ by $p_n+1$ is always equal to $1$ yes that's what I thought you mean

Comment: I am quite certain there isn't any general way to determine for which primes $p$ that $p^2 + p + 1$ is also prime.  When you say "for which prime numbers", are you referring to a specific interval?  If so, what interval is it?  It might also help if you provide some context for why you are asking this question.

Comment: Sorry I don't know if working in modulo $p+1$ is going to tell you anything about primality here, when you take $n^2+n+1$ modulo $n+1$ the same result occurs regarding what you refer to as the residue yes?

Comment: But yes John is correct the question as to how many such primes exist is a very difficult question that I would assume to be open

Comment: Note that for $p = 2$, $p^2 + p + 1$ is $7$, which is prime, but not included in your list.  Next, for $p = 3$, we have $p^2 + p + 1$ is $13$, which is also prime but not included in your list.  Also, for $p = 5$, the value becomes $31$, which is once again prime, and between your first $2$ listed values.  I haven't checked any more, but is there possibly an error in the equation you want to determine are primes?  Note I considered it to be "not" prime instead, but $p = 17$ gives $307$ which is also prime.

Comment: the smallest prime $p$ for which $p^2+p+1$ is **not**prime is $p=7$.     perhaps it will help you to build two disjoint subsets of $\mathbb P$, one whose elements adhere to your predicate and the other that violates it, (ie the one for which $7$ will be the smallest element)

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A053182

Comment: As for checking moduli, any general ones, such as $p + 1$, will usually not help very much.  However, you can easily find simple ones to remove large ranges of values of $p$ which could not work.  For example, all $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ produce a multiple of $3$, so those results can't be prime.  There are other fairly simple such congruences you can find and use to make it easier to check which results are definitely not prime.

Comment: I'm sorry for so many comments, but also note that $p^2 + p + 1 = \cfrac{p^3 - 1}{p - 1}$, so for all prime moduli $m$ where $p \equiv 1 \pmod m$ is not true but $p^3 \equiv 1 \pmod m$ is true will not generate a prime.  For example, this means that for all primes $p$ that have a remainder of 2 or 4 when divided by 7, $p^2 + p + 1$ will not be prime.

Answer (score 3):

The primes $p$ , for which $p^2+p+1=\frac{p^3-1}{p-1}$ is prime as well, cannot be classified. As mentioned in the comments, we can restrict $p$ , but basically to find the primes, we can only do brute force. There is no way to "predict" whether a prime $p$ does the job.

The Bunyakovsky conjecture implies that infinite many primes $p$ do the job, but it is unknown whether this is the case. In PARI/GP , the following routine calculates the primes upto a given limit :

```
? forprime(p=1,10^4,if(isprime(p^2+p+1)==1,print1(p," ")))
2 3 5 17 41 59 71 89 101 131 167 173 293 383 677 701 743 761 773 827 839 857 911
 1091 1097 1163 1181 1193 1217 1373 1427 1487 1559 1583 1709 1811 1847 1931 1973
 2129 2273 2309 2339 2411 2663 2729 2789 2957 2969 3011 3041 3137 3221 3251 3407
 3449 3491 3557 3671 3881 3989 4157 4217 4259 4409 4721 4733 4751 4877 4889 4973
 5003 5039 5087 5351 5501 5867 6047 6173 6389 6551 6569 6599 6653 6719 6761 6791
 6833 6917 7013 7229 7253 7547 7883 7901 8093 8231 8237 8387 8501 8543 8627 8669
 8681 8741 8753 8807 8963 9059 9323 9521 9533 9689 9719 9743 9749 9803
?
```

Comment: I noticed your comment on a recent prime-crank question. You may be interested to read [this](http://www.skepticblog.org/2010/07/08/martin-gardners-signs-of-a-crank) and [this](https://scienceblogs.com/denialism/2007/04/30/unified-theory-of-the-crank) to 'understand' why they do that.